# Correctly parsing a multipart-form response from API with different Content-Types on client side javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, multipartform-data, client-side, multipart

I´m stuck with the following problem:

Through an API Request I get an multipart-form response which contains three files in total:

1. Metadata in JSON
2. 3D Data in OBJ or STL as an octetstream
3. An Image as an octetstream

This is my Ajax request (tried it with fetch API aswell but failed so I thought I give the old AJAX request a shot)

```
    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("scanFormatEncoding", "obj");
      },
      type: "GET",
      url: this.baseurl + this.scansEndpoint + "/" + this.ScanSessionID,
      data: params,
      xhrFields: {
        responseType: "blob",
      },
      success: function (blob, status, xhr) {}
```

EDIT: Also my request with the fetch API

```
   fetch(this.baseurl + this.scansEndpoint + "/" + this.ScanSessionID, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        scanFormatEncoding: "obj",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        Accept: "*/*",
      },
    }).then((response) =>
      response.formData().then(function (formdata) {
      })
    );
```

And here the Response Header where you can see the Content-Type:

[image: My Response Header]

When I convert the blob to text I can verify, that all data appears to be in the multipart response.
However when I tried to parse it with an own parsing approach I tend to fail to parse the binary data of the image correct. So my question is, how can I achieve a parsing of all 3 files without worying about the different filetypes?

I already searched for solutions but could only find some for node.js and not client-sided JS.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the code you pasted in the question works correctly and you receive the complete multipart mime object. What is not working is the code you don't show, which tries to split the multipart object into its individual parts. If that's true, you should paste the code which doesn't work rather than (or in addition to) the code which does work, because it's hard to help you with code we can't see.

Comment: @rici thanks for your reply! The Code you mean was my mentioned attempt to parse the response as a string I guess. I throw the code snippet away since the binary part of the image could not get parsed correctly, thats why I tried to look forward to use the response.formData() method but this method tends to fail the parsing process so that is my current problem

Comment: What error do you get from `response.formData`?